# How to notify a parent CDialog that a child CWnd has been updated so that another child control can update in response?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have created a custom control as a derived class of `CWnd` that selects a sub-range from a range.  To test, I created a MFC Dialog Application in Visual Studio 2010 with a member instance of my custom class and some member `CEdit` instances to display the currently selected range from the custom control.

In the custom class, I have:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CRangeSelectorCtrl, CWnd)
  ...
  ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
  ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

...

void CRangeSelectorCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
  if (leftScrollArrowRect().PtInRect(point))
  {
    d_range_selector.SlideBar(-1);
    Invalidate();
  }
  else if (rightScrollArrowRect().PtInRect(point))
  {
    d_range_selector.SlideBar(1);
    Invalidate();
  }
  CWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

In my test dialog app, I have:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestRangeSelectorCtrlDlg, CDialogEx)
  ...
  ON_WM_PARENTNOTIFY()
  ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
...
BOOL CTestRangeSelectorCtrlDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
  ...
  m_range_selector_ctrl.ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY, 0);
   ...
}
...
void CTestRangeSelectorCtrlDlg::OnParentNotify(UINT message, LPARAM lParam)
{
  CDialogEx::OnParentNotify(message, lParam);
  if (message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
  {
    updateEditBoxes();
  } 
}
```

This almost works, but the problem is that the dialog's `OnParentNotify` get's called before the child has updated in response to the left-click so the values are all behind by one click.

How can I make `OnParentNotify` or another method in the parent be called after `OnLButtonDown` finishes in the child?  Or is there another way to accomplish what I want?

I have tried having the parent respond to `WM_LBUTTONUP` messages but when I add message handlers for `WM_LBUTTONUP` in the child and check for them in `OnParentNotify()` they are called in the child but never propagate to the parent (this is true even when I comment out the `CWnd::OnLButtonDown` call in `CWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point)`.

Comment: On further research, I realize that `OnParentNotify` is only called in response to a limited subset of messages which does not include `WM_LBUTTONUP`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fcz9fdd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own custom message and use it to notify the parent window of anything you want.

```
#define UWM_RANGE_CHANGE (WM_APP + 2) // a custom Windows message

GetParent()->PostMessage(UWM_RANGE_CHANGE, wParam, lParam);

To process the message the parent's message map needs:

ON_MESSAGE(UWM_RANGE_CHANGE, OnRangeChange)

and the message handler function must have this signature:

LRESULT Cxx:OnRangeChange(WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{

}
```

Pass any parameters you like in `wParam` and `lParam`. I have shown `PostMessage` above, which puts the message in the queue and returns, so the processing will be delayed until after your control functions return to the message pump. You can also use `SendMessage`: The message will be processed during the `SendMessage` call.

Comment: this certainly would work, but somehow it *feels* wrong. Wouldn't there be a de facto standard approach to the problem as presented (interdependent controls on a dialog)?? Just musing ...

Comment: I ended up solving with a similar approach except I used `NM_CLICK` instead of a custom notification message and used `SendNotifyMessage` instead of `PostMessage`

Answer (score 1):

The suggested answer would certainly work.  However, if you really want to control the updating from the custom control all you need to do is pass a pointer (and save it to a member variable) to the dialog controls you would like to update from the custom control.  You can do this through a method of the custom control, or, when it is instantiated.